# Convergence of a sequence pointwise a.e. on a manifold given that it converges on a reference manifold

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, continuity, manifolds

Let $\Gamma_t$ be a compact hypersurface for each $t \in [0,T]$. Let $Q=\Gamma_0\times(0,T)$ and $$Q_T :=\bigcup_{t \in (0,T)} \Gamma_t \times \{t\}.$$

For each $t \in [0,T]$, suppose that $F^t_0:\Gamma_t \to \Gamma_0$ is a $C^k$-diffeomorphism with inverse $F^0_t:\Gamma_0 \to \Gamma_t$.

We are given functions $\tilde u_n: Q \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\tilde u:Q \to \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$\tilde u_n\to \tilde u\quad \text{pointwise a.e. in $Q$}.$$ I want to show that the functions $u_n$
satisfy
$$\tilde u_n(F^{(\cdot)}_0, \cdot) \to \tilde u(F^{(\cdot)}_0, \cdot)\quad\text{pointwise a.e. in $Q_T$,}$$
i.e. that the pushforwards of sequence converges to the pushforward of the limit pointwise a.e.

---

**Incomplete proof**

Now we are given that for all $(x,t) \in Q\backslash Z$ (where $Z \subset Q$ is a set of measure zero) and every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ such that if $n > N$, we have
$$|\tilde u_n(x,t) - \tilde u(x,t)| < \epsilon$$
which can be written as
$$|\tilde u_n(F^t_0(y),t) - \tilde u(F^t_0(y),t)| < \epsilon$$
where $y = F^0_t(x)$.

Now I don't know what to do.. how do I map null sets of $Q$ to null sets of $Q_T$ in the right way to achieve the result?

Comment: You have to say more on dependence of $F_t^0$ on $t$. If you assume, say, that the map $(x,t)\mapsto (F^t_0(x), t)$ is a homeomorphism $Q\to Q_T$, then what you want indeed holds. However, if you make no such assumption then one can make some silly counterexamples. Here I was tacitly assuming that the manifolds $\Gamma_T$ are pairwise disjoint, otherwise your maps $\tilde u$ may not even be well-defined.

Comment: @studiosus Thanks for the comment, I will  think about it. If by pairwise disjoint you meant $\Gamma_s \cap \Gamma_t$ is empty then that is definitely not the case here. Why would $\tilde u$ be not well-defined?

Comment: Try to define them and see what happens.

Comment: I don't see the problem.. this set-up is in the literature anyway: see http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.6155.

Comment: Then, please, define what you mean by $\tilde{u}_n(F_0^{(\cdot)}, \cdot)$; as it stands, this is an undefined object.

Comment: Oh, never mind: I just notice that in the definition of $Q_T$ you multiply by $t$, which makes these hypersurfaces disjoint in the space one dimension higher.